Unitarily equivalent von Neumann algebras
Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be von Neumann algebras acting on the separable Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$ respectively.
Fact 1: If $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are unitarily equivalent then $\mathcal{A}\cong \mathcal{B}$ as well as $\mathcal{A}^\prime \cong \mathcal{B}^\prime.$
Question: Conversely, suppose that $\mathcal{A}\cong \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A}^\prime\cong \mathcal{B}^\prime.$ Which extra condition should be added for $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ to be unitarily equivalent ?
Thanks in advance.

What kind of condition are you expecting? What kind of condition implies unitary equivalence in this context?

This is certainly not true in general. For example, when $A$ is a II$_1$ factor with nontrivial fundamental group, and $t \in (0, \infty) \setminus {1}$ be an element of the said fundamental group, then the $A$-modules with continuous dimensions $1$ and $t$ satisfy the conditions you write down ($A \simeq B$ and $A’ \simeq A^{op} \simeq B’$), but they are not unitarily equivalent as the continuous dimension is preserved by unitary equivalence and $t \neq 1$.

Dear friends thank you for your answers. 1) If $A$ and $B$ are $*$-isomorphic, then there exists a separable Hilbert space $L$ and a unitary $V\colon H\times L\to K\times L$ such that $A\otimes \mathbb{C} I_{L}$ and $B\otimes \mathbb{C} I_{L}$ are unitarily equivalent through $V$.

Also, let $A$ be a type $II_1$ factor with $F(A)=\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}.$ Then, there exists a projection $P$ in $A$ such that $A\cong P A P$ as well as $A'\cong P A' P.$ So @David Gao, is this what you said above regardless to continuous dimensions?

@E.Papapetros More or less, yes.

I retract all of my previous comments except for the type II$_1$ counterexample. I was confusing myself. This is just a matter of the equivalence classes of projections in $A’ \otimes B(l^2)$. So for type I, the result is true (because the dimension of $A’$ gives you the trace of the projection). The same goes for type III. (You don’t even need $A’ \simeq B’$ in that case since all nonzero projections in a type III factor are equivalent.)

For type II$1$ and type II$\infty$, this depends on the fundamental group. For type II$_1$, if $F(A) = {1}$, then the result is true. Otherwise you have counterexamples (in any counterexample we must have $A’$ is type II$1$). For type II$\infty$, write $A = M \otimes B(l^2)$ where $M$ is of type II$_1$. Then if $F(M) = {1}$, the result is true (trivial fundamental group means the equivalence class of $A’$ distinguishes between different traces). Otherwise there are counterexamples (again, in any counterexample we must have $A’$ is type II$_1$).

All of the above only works if one (and therefore all) of $A$, $A’$, $B$, $B’$ is a factor. Otherwise, none of this is going to be true. Even in type I, say, you could have $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}^2$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^2 \oplus \mathbb{C}^2$ or on $\mathbb{C} \oplus (\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2)$.
